# Rails mailer, associated with a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I need a kind of mailer, that is associated with a model.

For example, it should notify subscribers, when, e.g. message is posted in a topic in question.

I should see, that mails are delivered, how much recipients, mail body etc.

AFAIK, standard ActionMailer in Rails 2.3 does't have a deal with storing something in DB.

Is there any GEM or plugin for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try [ActiveRecord Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) to tap into model lifecycle events and trigger your mail generation. You could write some sort of tallying system to keep track of the metrics you mention.